# How to handle service stopped in background

Tags: android, android-service

My ex colleague developed a service which plays music in background. However if user wants to exit from program then application calls below code to stop service. Service stops but i cannot handle it while overriding onDestroy method

```
    Activity realAct = context.getParent();
    if (realAct == null) {
        realAct = context;
    }
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(realAct);

    cw.stopService(new Intent(cw, MyPlayerService.class));
```

edit:
Briefly, Activity Main starts Activity Sub then Activity Sub starts Service. Then i press back button so Activity Sub finishes. When i am in Activity Main I call above stopservice code. So onDestroy method of Service is not called

Answer (score 0):

Try again to use method like that in code of your service :

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
super.onDestroy();
//your code
}
```

It has to work !

Comment: Below code was never called, I tried many times

@Override
 public void onDestroy() {
  Log.e(LOG_SERVICE, "SERVICE onDestroy");
  super.onDestroy();
 }

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to stop the service when the user exits from application?

onDestroy is called when system needs to kill activities due to insufficient resources. Just because you pressed back on your app doesn't mean onDestroy gets called immediately.

But if you want to force close your app to have it automatically invoke onDestroy, call

> finish()

on wherever you are exiting your application from.

If you want to invoke onDestroy upon user pressing back button to exit, Override onBackPressed() and invoke finish() from there.

But really, this is an antipattern so I'd recommend using onPause() instead.

Edit Upon OP Edit:

I think we need to have more details on how you are instantiating the service but here are some additional thoughts:

Have you overridden onDestroy properly and calling the super method?

If this is the case, the only other possibility I can think of is that you still have ServiceConnection objects bound to the service with BIND_AUTO_CREATE set. Until all of these bindings are removed, service will not get destroyed.

So make sure to do both:

```
unbindService(conn);
stopService(intent);
```

Comment: Dear  friend i am going to update my question again. 
Briefly, 
Activity Main starts Activity Sub then Activity Sub starts Service. Then i press back button so Activity Sub finishes. When i am in Activity Main I call above stopservice code. So onDestroy method of Service is not called

Comment: @WinstonSmith Ok, so to sum it up, you are saying that the onDestroy method that is inside the service is never called even though you are calling stopService from the mainactivity as soon as the user exits out of subactivity, am I correct?

Comment: yes you are correct and now I am stuck of the project and cannot solve it